# Can't hear any sound on True Skate

Tags: true-skate

On my iPad 3 I am playing True Skate and I can't seem to hear any sound coming from the game, but in other games I can hear sound. I have reinstalled the game and I have checked all of the settings.
Does anybody know any answers, is it a bug in the game?

Comment: Make sure the switch on the side is not on. Try flipping it and if you see a bell with a line thru it then it's the app. If that doesn't work try another device (if possible).

Comment: Ok ill try that tomorrow